# How to remove a specific character only from the first word in a line for every column?

Tags: awk, sed, append, character

File in:

```
1 34566 34765 
2 45678 45789
Scaffold_3 34567 34799
Scaffold_X 67895 66900
Scaffold_Y 34567 34890
```

**Note**: There are lots of lines. I want to remove only underscore (`_`) from the words in the first column. There should be no other changes except this. I am learning sed and Awk so any commands using these tools would be helpful. Additionally, explanation would also be helpful.

File out:

```
1 34566 34765 
2 45678 45789
Scaffold3 34567 34799
ScaffoldX 67895 66900
ScaffoldY 34567 34890
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your input file a little to demonstrate that only the underscore in the first column is removed:

```
1 34_566 34765
2 45678 45_789
Scaffold_3 345_67 34799
Scaffold_X 678_95 66900
Scaffold_Y 345_67 34890
```

As for removing the underscore, I've used sed:

```
$ sed 's/^\([^ _]*\)_/\1/' infile 
1 34_566 34765
2 45678 45_789
Scaffold3 345_67 34799
ScaffoldX 678_95 66900
ScaffoldY 345_67 34890
```

The command uses a *substitution*. We match all the characters that are neither spaces nor underscores and capture them:`\([^ _]*\)`. This expression gets anchored at the start of the string (the first `^`) and is followed by an underscore.

We then replace it by what we have captured, but leave the underscore out (the `\1` backreference in the replacement string).

---

#### Multiple underscores in the first column

Should there be more than one underscore in the first column, it gets a little tricky with sed. There are basically two options:

1. Try to replace an underscore in the first column (like above), repeat this action until no more changes take place so we know all the underscores in the first column are gone.
2. Keep only the first column in the pattern space, replace all underscores globally, get the whole line back and replace the old with the new first column.

Here is an implementation of the **first approach**:

```
sed '
:a                  # Label to jump to
s/^\([^ _]*\)_/\1/  # Replace underscore in first column (like above)
ta                  # Jump to label if something was changed
' infile
```

And this is an implementation of the **second approach**:

```
sed '
h                    # Copy pattern space to hold space
s/^\([^ ]*\).*/\1/   # Remove everything but the first column
s/_//g               # Delete all underscores
G                    # Append hold space to pattern space

# Replace old first column with underscore-free first column
s/^\(.*\)\n[^ ]*\(.*\)/\1\2/
' infile
```

The last step is the trickiest one. Before it, our pattern space looks like this (assuming an input file with multiple underscores in the first column):

```
ScaffoldY\nSca_ffold_Y 345_67 34890$
^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
New col 1      Old complete line
```

We replace the old first column with the new first column by smartly capturing and replacing:

```
ScaffoldY\nSca_ffold_Y 345_67 34890$
^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    \1                      \2
```

So for an input file that looks like

```
1 34_566 34765
2 45678 45_789
Sca_ffold_3 345_67 34799
Sca_ffold_X 678_95 66900
Sca_ffold_Y 345_67 34890
```

we get output like this (with the command compressed to a single line):

```
$ sed 'h;s/^\([^ ]*\).*/\1/;s/_//g;G;s/^\(.*\)\n[^ ]*\(.*\)/\1\2/' infile 
1 34_566 34765
2 45678 45_789
Scaffold3 345_67 34799
ScaffoldX 678_95 66900
ScaffoldY 345_67 34890
```

---

#### Remark

Notice that if the input files are not space separated, this won't work. The spaces in the bracket expressions have to be changed to reflect, e.g., tab separation. The first solution becomes

```
sed 's/^\([^[:blank:]_]*\)_/\1/' infile
```

the second one

```
sed ':a;s/^\([^[:blank:]_]*\)_/\1/;ta' infile
```

and the third one

```
sed 'h;s/^\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/;s/_//g;G;s/^\(.*\)\n[^[:blank:]]*\(.*\)/\1\2/' infile
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I think I have learned something. I will try to implement this education to other replacements I want to make.

Comment: @everestial007 One learning could be that it's simpler with awk ;)

Comment: Hi, @Benjamin W. : But, unfortunately this is only working when the columns are space separated. Not working when they are tab separated. Please see the output: 1 34566 34765
2 45678 45789
Scaffold3 345_67 34799
ScaffoldX 678_95 66900
ScaffoldY 345_67 34890

Comment: @everestial007 Replace all instances of spaces in bracket expressions with `[:blank:]`, as in `sed'h;/s^\([^[:blank:]]*\)...` - this covers both spaces and tabs.

Comment: @everestial007 See remark at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

This awk one-liner should do the job:

```
awk '{gsub(/_/,"",$1)}1' input.txt
```

Output:

```
1 34566 34765 
2 45678 45789
Scaffold3 34567 34799
ScaffoldX 67895 66900
ScaffoldY 34567 34890
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the underscore as your field separator (-F) instead of the default whitespace:

```
awk -F'_' '{print $1$2}' file.txt
```

Comment: This, too, replaces underscores in columns other than the first.

Comment: That's true, I was working under the assumption other columns contained just numbers. A risky assumption.